# Optimizing a parallel_for implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, parallel.for

I had some code which used Microsofts PPL to do parallel_for loops, and then I had to move that to Linux and Mac which made me make my own version. It does what is should and it does it with decent performance, but it is still some 20% slower than an otherwise identical PPL parallel_for loop.

I should perhaps mention that commonly 10 thousand to 100 thousand iterations are being executed, but each iteration is only a couple of square roots and multiplications. It has to run very fast, though, since it is for an interactive application.

Still new to C++ 11 so I would love it if someone more experienced could take a look at my implementation and give some feedback as to why it is not all the way there and what could be improved.

```
template<size_t THREADS_PER_CORE = 1>
void parallel_forMine(size_t start, size_t end, const std::function<void(size_t)> &userLambda)
{
    int threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()*THREADS_PER_CORE;

    int blockSize = (end - start) / threadCount;
    if (blockSize*threadCount < end - start)
        blockSize++;

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    int blockStart = start;
    int blockEnd = blockStart + blockSize;
    if (blockEnd > end) blockEnd = end;

    for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < threadCount; threadIndex++)
    {
        futures.push_back(std::move(std::async(std::launch::async, [blockStart, blockEnd, &userLambda]
        {
            for (size_t i = blockStart; i < blockEnd; ++i)
            {
                userLambda(i);
            }
        })));

        blockStart += blockSize;
        blockEnd = blockStart + blockSize;
        if (blockStart >= end) break;
        if (blockEnd > end) blockEnd = end;
    }

    for (std::future<void> &f: futures)
        f.get();
}
```

The full test code is below.

```
#include "stdafx.h" //nothing in there in this test
#include <ppl.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

template<size_t THREADS_PER_CORE = 1>
void parallel_forMine(size_t start, size_t end, const std::function<void(size_t)> &userLambda)
{
int threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()*THREADS_PER_CORE;

int blockSize = (end - start) / threadCount;
if (blockSize*threadCount < end - start)
    blockSize++;

std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

int blockStart = start;
int blockEnd = blockStart + blockSize;
if (blockEnd > end) blockEnd = end;

for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < threadCount; threadIndex++)
{
    futures.push_back(std::move(std::async(std::launch::async, [blockStart, blockEnd, &userLambda]
    {
        for (size_t i = blockStart; i < blockEnd; ++i)
        {
            userLambda(i);
        }
    })));

    blockStart += blockSize;
    blockEnd = blockStart + blockSize;
    if (blockStart >= end) break;
    if (blockEnd > end) blockEnd = end;
}

for (std::future<void> &f: futures)
    f.get();
}



int main()
{
    //serial execution
    std::vector<double> valueSerial(1000);
    auto startSerial = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
            valueSerial[i] += sqrt(abs(cos(sin(sqrt(i)))));
    auto durationSerial = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startSerial).count() / 1000;
    std::cout << durationSerial << " Serial" << std::endl;


//PPL parallel for
std::vector<double> valueParallelForPPL(1000);
auto startParallelForPPL = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
Concurrency::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(1000), [&](size_t i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
        valueParallelForPPL[i] += sqrt(abs(cos(sin(sqrt(i)))));
});
auto durationParallelForPPL = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startParallelForPPL).count() / 1000;
std::cout << durationParallelForPPL << " PPL parallel for"<<std::endl;


//my parallel for
std::vector<double> valueParallelFor(1000);
auto startParallelFor = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
parallel_forMine(0, 1000, [&](size_t i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
        valueParallelFor[i] += sqrt(abs(cos(sin(sqrt(i)))));
});
auto durationParallelFor = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startParallelFor).count() / 1000;
std::cout << durationParallelFor << " My parallel for"<<std::endl;


//only really to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize everything away
for (int i = 0; i < valueSerial.size();i++)
    if (valueSerial[i] != valueParallelFor[i] || valueParallelFor[i]!= valueParallelForPPL[i])
        std::cout << "error";


std::cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a special site for [code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: can you post a complete test program please? then we can check for performance bottlenecks easily (and so can you!!!)

Comment: The `move` in `std::move(std::async` is useless.

Comment: Richard, I added the timing code.
Jarod, you are correct. I think it is a leftover from when I stored the future in a local var before pushing it. The very interesting thing is that when removing the move my code is actually about 10% faster than PPL now! I need to look more into that, because that is surprising. Thanks!

Comment: I would use a thread pool and task queue instead of creating throw away threads then destroying them.

Comment: Yakk, std::async is likely using a pool. Can also add the comment that the default launch policy made it run serial on linux for some reason.

Comment: @JoeTaicoon It cannot in practice use a bounded pool (without a lot of fancy machinery), because there can be arbitrary dependencies between the various asyncs.  Every async must advance eventually, both in practice and in theory.  Unless you have confirmed the use of a thread pool in every platform you care about (and into the future), at this point (only 4 years after C++11 release) I wouldn't presume a maximally optimal std implementation.

Comment: @Yakk: Valid point. The pool can obviously run dry with launch::async. Given the number of simultaneous threads I will run, that does not strike me as likely, but, yes, you are right of course.

Comment: @JoeTaicoon Rather, I am saying that `std::async` cannot be managing a bounded pool.  It could recycle threads rather than create a new one on each call; but even then it has to deal with thread_local storage issues (whatever implementation has to construct and destroy all thread_local objects as if it was a new thread).  What I'm saying is that it is definitely worth considering comparing against a manually written thread pool.  (Note that `std::thread` could recycle lower-level threads almost as easily as `std::async`)